# package problem

Tags: java, class, package, javac

we make a class in java in one package. example

```
package p1;
class protection{
 int a=2;
}
```

and then we save this. with protection.java and compile this class compiles easily - no error. Then we make other class in same packge derived and extend the class protection and save this with derived.java example

```
package p1;
class derived extends protection{
derived(){
System.out.println(a);
}
}
```

but when we compile this comes an error:

> "class protectiion not found"

and not acccess the integer a;
but in book write "sub class in same package access the member". but this is not compile and not access the class. how we do this. Please if you know then help me..

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your two classes. Please check again for typos (in your error message e.g. you wrong "protectiion" although the classname is "protection").

Comment: Works for me. How did you compile it? Especially: Where did the output, p1.protection go? Please provide detailed, complete information. Thanks

Comment: or is protection class name starts with capital letter?

Comment: I made a subdir named "p1" put into it both java files and ran command `javac p1/derived.java`. Class files were then also in "p1".

Comment: It sounds like it may be a classpath issue.  Try javac -classpath . p1/derived.java so that it can find p1/protection.class

Answer (score 2):

If you are already in p1 when compiling, the other class is searched for in p1/p1/, because the first p1 is the current dir.

```
javac -cp .. derived.java
```

should do it.

A better, more clear idea is, to

```
cd ..
javac p1/derived.java
```

Then 'derived' and 'protected' live close and peaceful together.